# Lower bounded wildcards in java

Tags: java, generics, wildcard

Consider the following example,

```
List<? super Number> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
list1.add(10);
list1.add(10.10);
list1.add(20.20d);
```

and another list to which i assign **list1**

```
List<? super Integer> list = list1;
System.out.println(list.toString());
```

Now, when i print the list it contains double values also *BUT the list is only supposed to hold Integer and anything above Integer*.

If the above is fine then shouldn't the following compile as well ?

```
list.add(30.30);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between <? super T> and <? extends T> in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343202/difference-between-super-t-and-extends-t-in-java)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4343547/1270003 This answer tells you that  to write (add) to a list, you need to use `super`, while to read (toString), you need to declare it using `extends` (e.g. `list`), and that will give you a compiler warning. This is probably the unsafe downside of Java

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Everything makes sense if you consider the possible things you could assign to it.

```
List<? super Number> list1 = new ArrayList<Object>(); // works
List<? super Number> list1 = new ArrayList<Number>(); // works
List<? super Number> list1 = new ArrayList<Integer>(); // doesn't work
```

Anything that works on the right hand side will accept a `Double`.

```
List<? super Integer> list = new ArrayList<Object>(); // works
List<? super Integer> list = new ArrayList<Number>(); // works
List<? super Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(); // works
```

Anything that you could assign to `list1` you could also assign to `list`.  So `list = list1` works just fine.  But *not* all of the things you could assign to `list` will accept a `Double`, so it doesn't compile.

Comment: Your two blocks are the same, except the comment on line 3. Copy/paste error? Shouldn't second block be `List<? super Integer>`?

Comment: Fixed the issue.

Comment: Why doesn't the following work?
`List<? super Number> list1 = new ArrayList<Integer>(); // doesn't work`

where as you can actually _add_ integers to it i.e. `list1.add(10)`. While initializing we are forcing the compiler to have only numbers but able to add integers. That means we can also _add_ objects down the hierarchy.

Comment: All these questions arise due to _type inference_ i.e. one can declare 
`List<? super Number> list1 = new ArrayList<>();`

Comment: Why would it?  Integer isn't a super type of Number.

Comment: Actually i should have asked _why shouldn't it_ :) ..what i mean to say is even if i define `List<? super Number> list = new ArrayList<Object>();`  , you cannot add `list.add(new Object())`. Whole thing of using `super` is to add objects but in the downstream hierarchy i.e. in the above case, `Number` or any subclass of `Number`.

Comment: A `List<? super Number>` can be anything from a `List<Object>` to a `List<Number>`.  Only operations that work for all those possibilities are allowed.  So anything you get out of the list could be an Object, but you can't add anything that isn't a Number.